# Sufficient condition for a quartic curve to be birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have come across a few sources which talks about transforming a quartic curve of the form
$y^2=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$ to an elliptic curve such as the Joseph H. Silverman's book- *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, Lawrence Washington's *Elliptic curves, Number theory and Cryptography* and also *Lectures on Elliptic curves* by J.W.S. Cassels. The minimum requirement mentioned in the first two books is the existence of  a rational point and the lack of singular points while Cassels transforms it just assuming the existence of rational points. I understand that elliptic curves must be non-singular. My question is whether it is sufficient for us to check the existence of rational points on the quartic curve in order to transform it to a cubic curve. Because if so, we can then check the singularity of the cubic to conclude if it is an elliptic curve or not.

Answer (score 2):

If the curve $X=V(y^2=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)\subset\Bbb A^2_k$ is nonsingular (equivalent to $Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$ having no repeated roots), then it defines a genus-one curve: the morphism $X\to\Bbb A^1_k$ by projecting to the $x$-axis extends to a degree-two morphism from the smooth compactification $\overline{X}\to\Bbb P^1$ which is ramified at the four points $X\cap V(y)$. By Riemann-Hurwitz, $$2g(\overline{X})-2=2(2g(\Bbb P^1)-2)+\sum_{x\in \overline{X}} (e_x-1),$$ so as $g(\Bbb P^1)=0$, $e_x=1$ for all non-ramified points, and $\sum_{x\mapsto y} e_x = 2$, we see that $g(\overline{X})=1$ and the morphism is unramified at infinity.

To determine if we get an elliptic curve, we need to check for the presence of a rational point. Let's see if we get one at infinity: embedding $X\subset\Bbb P^2$ in the standard way, we get the homogeneous equation $y^2z^2=Ax^4+Bx^3z+Cx^2z^2+Dxz^3+Ez^4$, and we need to look at points on $z=0$ which are contained in the chart $D(y)$. Dehomogenizing with respect to $y$, we get the equation $$z^2=Ax^4+Bx^3z+Cx^2z^2+Dxz^3+Ez^4,$$ which is singular at $x=0$, $z=0$. Blowing up via $z=tx$, this becomes $$t^2=Ax^2+Bx^2t+Cx^2t^2+Dx^2t^3+Ex^2t^4$$ which is still singular at $x=0,t=0$; blowing up again via $t=ux$ gives $$u^2=A^2+Bux+Cu^2x^2+Du^3x^3+Eu^4x^4$$ which is nonsingular on the line $x=0$. There's a rational point on $x=0$ (i.e. a rational point on $\overline{X}$ over $\infty\in\Bbb P^1$) iff $A$ is a square in $k$.

In summary, you get an elliptic curve iff $Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E$ has no repeated roots and at least one of the following is true: $A$ is a square in $k$ or $V(y^2=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)\subset\Bbb A^2_k$ has a $k$-rational point.